# <p:autocomplete> inside <ui:repetition> retains old data

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I observed a fairly strange behaviour I can't seem to find an explanation for. The following  structure renders a list of line-up entries for football matches:

```
<h:head/>
<h:body>
<ui:composition xmlns:teams="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/teams">
  <h:panelGroup id="layerFragment">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{abean.showLayer}">
        <ui:repeat var="e" value="#{abean.bbean.entries}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{status.index+1}" />.</td>
            <td>
                 <h:selectOneMenu id="position" value="#{e.position}"                 
                    converter="PositionConverter">
                      <f:selectItems value="#{abean.positions}" />
                 </h:selectOneMenu>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:outputLabel class="inv" for="name" value="#{e.player}" />
                <p:autoComplete id="name" value="#{e.spieler}" 
                   completeMethod="#{abean.completePlayer}" var="s1" 
                   itemLabel="#{s1.name}" itemValue="#{s1}"         
                    converter="SpielerConverter">
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
                         listener="#{abean.playerCompleted}" update="position"/> 
                </p:autoComplete>
            </td>                                                       
        </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
        ...
```

As you can see, it contains an autocomplete field and a drop-down per row, but alltogether it's completely vanilla. Now I got this embedded in a component, that is overlayed from a command link. When I click on it, the overlay is displayed and the line-up rendered.

This can be invoked from a list of line-ups, is overlayed and rendered. All of which works fine. Except for the fact, that the p:autocomplete gets the FIRST entry wrong! I double-checked, the repetition gets the correct values. However, p:autocomplete seems to retain only the **first** row from a previous run. And it's always the same row, too.

I am lost. Does someone know what is going on here? I'm using Primefaces 3.5 btw.

Edit: here is the component above it in the hierarchy. The popup is defined in layer.xhtml. The line-up list in leftcolumn.xhtml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition template="/admin/template/master_layout.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<ui:param name="viewName" value="ticker" />
<ui:define name="windowTitle">Tickern</ui:define>

<ui:define name="leftcolumn">
    <ui:include src="/fussball/leftcolumn.xhtml" />
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="breadcrumb">
    <ui:include src="/fussball/breadcrumb.xhtml" />
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
    <ui:include src="/fussball/ticker.xhtml" />
</ui:define>

<ui:define name="layer">
    <ui:include src="/fussball/layer.xhtml" />
</ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: The key may be the part that you don't show here, that is, how you update the autocomplete.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'update the autocomplete'?

Comment: I mean, JSF partial update

Comment: I still don't follow, I am afraid. The problem appears right from the getgo. It seems the value binding of the autocomplete is wrong. 

What's  more: I found out, that the trouble only starts when there are multiple line-ups to choose from (that means, the fragment acting as a placeholder for the pop-up that contains the autocomplete can be filled with content from different line-ups). If  there is only one choice, everything works fine. But then again, that is not soo surprising. 

Could this be some problem related to the ID of the p:autocomplete?

Comment: I went ahead and gave every p:autocomplete a unique ID. No cigar.

Comment: Edited the question to contain the component above it.

Comment: Why in earth did you tag this question with `[jsf-1.2]`? This is clearly JSF 2.x code.

Comment: Sorry, I am still quite new to JSF/Primefaces. Thanks for the friendly pointer, I removed the tag.

Comment: Me too have the same problem. I am using <p:autocomplete in p:datatable.

Comment: Good to know I am not alone. I have not been able to find a solution to the problem yet.